# HTML5 default audio player CSS styling

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio

I am trying to edit the background colour (so that it has 100 transparency) of the play button in the default audio control with CSS.

Already tried this:

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.99);
}
```

And this:

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

The only thing I am getting is a black square where the play button's image is meant to be.

Comment: put your code in fiddle or plunker?

Comment: i think problem is z-index. set  z-index=1 or  z-index=0

Answer (score 0):

The style selector and style you are using works, but, since it's **-webkit-** based, works only on webkit based browsers, try your code in Chrome, I tried following, and it worked for me:

```
<style>
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
  background-color: rgba(230, 230, 255, 1);
}
</style>
```

By default HTML5 Audio/Video player display default control of browser. You can chose to customize them via CSS and Javascript, or use something like jPlayer as @Jainam suggested, or you can use: [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) or [audio.js](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/)

There are tons of jQuery plugins for doing just what you are looking for, and if you want to just display a customized audio player, I'll suggest that you use one of these.

You can have a look at following example to customize the audio player for you: http://authenticstyle.co.uk/html5-audio-player/